# How to get just USB IDs of all plugged in devices in linux

Tags: linux, shell, usb, python-2.x

I am trying to make a Python script which runs in the background and checks the USB IDs of all plugged in devices to see if it matches a list of recognized IDs. This is going to be ran in a Linux environment with preferably Python 2.x

I know in in linux I can run `lsusb` in a shell or run it through `os.system()` and that will give me this output:

```
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 046d:082b Logitech, Inc. Webcam C170
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 1532:0043 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 010: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0424:2137 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0451:8044 Texas Instruments, Inc.
```

However, as you can see this returns way more information than I need and filtering through this will be difficult and take more time. What i need would be something like this:

```
046d:c534
046d:082b
1532:0043
05e3:0608
05e3:0608
0424:2137
0451:8044
```

In the interest of keeping this script as fast as possible, is there some way that I can run a command to the system and get back just the USB IDs of everything plugged in, or use `grep` or something similar in Python to filter through it somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you kindly add a sample of what your expected output is? Are you expecting something like `<bus#>:<device#>` or _just_ `Bus 003 Device 001`?

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: @jww please refer to the paragraph directly above the first code block. I believe this paragraph contains the code you wish to see that gives the output displayed in said first code block. (`lsusb` in shell or `os.system("lsusb")` in Python.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this solve your problem?

```
guru@dileant:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 2687:fb01  
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8009 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The following solutions use `sed` (stream editor) to print only the relevant parts of the output. This program uses a perl-like syntax to do string replacements. Thus, the command lines are often of the form: `sed <flags> 's/<find>/<replace>/g'`.

Finally, `sed` uses `\(  \)` to denote regex groups. You can use regex groups when you want to retain certain parts of the input pattern.

Thus, if you want the Bus and Device numbers, you could do:

```
guru@dileant:~$ lsusb | sed -e 's/Bus \([0-9]\+\) Device \([0-9]\+\).*/\1:\2/g'
002:002
002:001
006:001
005:003
005:002
005:001
001:002
001:001
```

Likewise, if you wanted the vendor and product IDs, you could do:

```
guru@dileant:~$ lsusb | sed -e 's/.*ID \([a-f0-9]\+:[a-f0-9]\+\).*/\1/g'
8087:8001
1d6b:0002
1d6b:0003
2687:fb01  
0a5c:21e8
1d6b:0002
8087:8009
1d6b:0002
```

Answer (score 1):

[PyUSB](https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb) has the functionality you need and much more.

You can use the following code (compatible with Python2 and Python3) to enumerate all devices currently connected:

```
import usb.core
for dev in usb.core.find(find_all=True):
  print("%0.4X:%0.4X" % (dev.idVendor, dev.idProduct))
```

the `dev` object will have VID, PID and all the other device attributes.
Example output:

```
046D:C016
413C:2107
8087:0024
```

They also got a [tutorial](https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst), if one wants to interact with a USB device